# Mac: Replace "users/<computer-name>" in all terminals

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, iterm2, computer-name

I'm running into an issue with hiding my computer name. I want all terminal outputs on my mac (iTerm ->zsh & IntelliJ) to stop showing my computer name and show ~/. Can someone help me achieve this, I'm not sure what setting I'm looking to change.

**ie.**

*From*

users/ComputerName/app/src/main/java/com/virtualprodigy/android_compose_template

*To*

~/app/src/main/java/com/virtualprodigy/android_compose_template

Answer (score 1):

Prompt format in zsh is controlled by `PROMPT` or `PS1` variable. You can check if one of these variables is set up in `~/.zshrc` (if there's no such file, create it by running `touch ~/.zshrc`).

If in your .zshrc you see a line setting either `PROMPT` or `PS1`, in its value substitute `%/` (absolute path) with `%~` (relative to home path).

If there's no such line in your .zshrc, you can just add this:

```
PROMPT='%~ %# '
```

Then save the file and restart your terminal.

Comment: I'm not looking to change the prompt, my prompt already hides my computer's user folder name. I want to change to terminal output for response to commands such as pwd.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the prompt in your terminal to display ~ instead of the full path by modifying your shell's configuration file.

For zsh, you can add the following line to your ~/.zshrc file:

```bash
PROMPT='%~ %# '
```

For bash, you can add this line to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc file:

```bash
PS1="\w \$ "
```

This will change the prompt to display only the current directory, represented by ~ for the home directory, and the command prompt symbol ($ for normal users, # for superusers).

You will need to either restart your terminal, or run the command `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes.